# Azure KeyVault Secret near expiry list to email as a notification

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm try to send List of secrets that are expired and about to expired to email ID .
But i cant able to see Secrets that are near about to expire.
is anybody help how to get near about to expiry secrets of azure keyVault?

i'm using below code :

```
    if ($secret.Expires) {
        $secretExpiration = Get-date $secret.Expires -Format yyyyMMdd
        if ($ExpirationDate -gt $secretExpiration) {
            if ($CurrentDate -lt $secretExpiration) {
                $NearExpirationSecrets += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Name           = $secret.Name;
                    Category       = 'SecretNearExpiration';
                    KeyVaultName   = $KeyVault.VaultName;
                    ExpirationDate = $secret.Expires;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try my script below, in my sample, `A secret that will expire in 7 days` means `secret is about to expired`, the script get all the secrets that are about to expired in a keyvault.

```
$KeyVault = Get-AzKeyVault -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -VaultName joykeyvault 
$secrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName joykeyvault 
$Date = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(7) -Format yyyyMMdd
$CurrentDate = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$NearExpirationSecrets = @()

foreach($secret in $secrets){
    if($secret.Expires) {
    $secretExpiration = Get-Date $secret.Expires -Format yyyyMMdd
    if($secretExpiration -lt $Date -and $secretExpiration -gt $CurrentDate){
           $NearExpirationSecrets += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    Name           = $secret.Name;
                    Category       = 'SecretNearExpiration';
                    KeyVaultName   = $KeyVault.VaultName;
                    ExpirationDate = $secret.Expires;
                }

    }
}
}
```

[image]